# How to get cell edit date in Google Sheets via API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have auto-updated Google Sheet with 1500+ rows. I need to fill new column with Dates when A-column cells were changed.

I have tried to get data from [Google Drive Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions), but I can't "look inside of the file" without downloading, cause this API provides only `exportLinks`.

How can I get cells edit dates via API or some other way?

It will be great to write smth like:

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
AColumn = sheet.getRange('A1:A')
ALastRow = AColumn.lastrow()

for (var i = 1; i < ALastRow: i++)
{ 
  cell = AColumn.getRange('A'+i)
  cellEditDate = cell.lastUpdate["date"]
  sheet.getRange('B'+i).setValue(cellEditDate)
}
```

Thanks!

P.S. From UI cell edit date can be obtained through [this feature](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/06/edit-history-sheets.html?m=1).