# How do I create a function that returns the last time a cell was modified?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm looking to write a function for Google Sheets Script that accepts a cell reference and outputs the date that cell was last modified. I'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485065/how-to-get-cell-edit-date-in-google-sheets-via-api

Comment: cross-site related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87620/access-google-spreadsheet-revision-history-through-api

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct approach to get the exact date of a cell's edit.

#### Method 1

Retrieve the `modifiedTime` using the Drive API's [`Files:get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) which will return, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource):

> The last time the file was modified by anyone (RFC 3339 date-time).

---

#### Method 2

What you can do instead is to make use of the `onEdit(e)` trigger and monitor *each change* from the particular cell.

So for example, considering that the cell you want to check is `A1`, you can use this snippet:

#### Snippet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above function is an `onEdit` trigger which will fire every time there's an edit made on the sheet. Since you want to check this for a **particular** cell, the event object `e` has been used in order to get the `row` and the `column` of the cell which has been edited. Therefore, the `if` condition in this situation checks if the `row` is equal to `1` and the column is equal to `1` (range corresponding to the `A1` cell) and based on that, it returns the **current date** which corresponds in this situation to the edit that has been made.

To track all the edits for a cell, you can store the `date` variables resulted from the edit to an array and eventually use it afterwards to your liking.

---

#### Note

Taking these into account, you won't be able to get the time of a cell which has been edited **before** having the trigger into place.

---

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get);
- [Drive API v3 Files Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).